# Publishing fails at commit in Cloud Search with SI4T

Tags: web8, si4t, sdl-cloud

This may be an interesting usecase for SI4T.

The publishing for a particular Page is failing with the following error in the deployer logs.

```
2017-04-10 12:29:53,006 ERROR TridionCommitStep - Commit failed for execution id:tcm:0-815932-66560
com.sdl.delivery.deployer.api.processing.exception.ProcessingException: Unable to commit transactions. ExecutionId:tcm:0-815932-66560
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionTransactionalExecutableStep.commitTransaction(TridionTransactionalExecutableStep.java:78)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionCommitStep.process(TridionCommitStep.java:28)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor.com$sdl$delivery$deployer$engine$pipeline$actor$StepActor$$execute(StepActor.scala:60)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(StepActor.scala:44)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:480)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor.aroundReceive(StepActor.scala:27)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: com.tridion.broker.StorageException: Commit failed for transaction tcm:0-815932-66560 because of com.tridion.storage.si4t.IndexingException: Configuration Exception:{ ["Field name (extendeddocumentType) must match the regex [a-z0-9][a-z0-9_]{0,63}$ (near operation with index 1; document_id tcm:22-24417-64)"] } (Service: AmazonCloudSearchDomain; Status Code: 400; Error Code: DocumentServiceException; Request ID: 65ccdead-1de9-11e7-8546-f34ef8b61642)
    at com.tridion.storage.management.TransactionManagerImpl.commitTransaction(TransactionManagerImpl.java:70)
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.commitTransaction(StorageManagerFactory.java:227)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionTransactionalExecutableStep.commitTransaction(TridionTransactionalExecutableStep.java:76)
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.tridion.broker.StorageException: com.tridion.storage.si4t.IndexingException: Configuration Exception:{ ["Field name (extendeddocumentType) must match the regex [a-z0-9][a-z0-9_]{0,63}$ (near operation with index 1; document_id tcm:22-24417-64)"] } (Service: AmazonCloudSearchDomain; Status Code: 400; Error Code: DocumentServiceException; Request ID: 65ccdead-1de9-11e7-8546-f34ef8b61642)
    at com.tridion.storage.si4t.JPASearchDAOFactory.commitTransaction(JPASearchDAOFactory.java:202)
    at com.tridion.storage.management.TransactionManagerImpl.commitTransaction(TransactionManagerImpl.java:65)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.tridion.storage.si4t.IndexingException: Configuration Exception:{ ["Field name (extendeddocumentType) must match the regex [a-z0-9][a-z0-9_]{0,63}$ (near operation with index 1; document_id tcm:22-24417-64)"] } (Service: AmazonCloudSearchDomain; Status Code: 400; Error Code: DocumentServiceException; Request ID: 65ccdead-1de9-11e7-8546-f34ef8b61642)
    at org.si4t.cloudsearch.CloudSearchIndexer.commit(CloudSearchIndexer.java:163)
    at com.tridion.storage.si4t.SearchIndexProcessor.triggerIndexing(SearchIndexProcessor.java:274)
    at com.tridion.storage.si4t.JPASearchDAOFactory.commitTransaction(JPASearchDAOFactory.java:189)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
```

Here `extendeddocumentType` is a metadata field of a Category as a Radio Button where there is a default value set.

There are few more similar fields `upgradepath` but not as Radio Button but Tree and those do not throw any error. Interestingly I do not see this field entry in my Page Template output in Template Builder. (see below)

Apart from that, in the below XML, field `product` is also a Category/Keyword based field and it is also listed in `<custom>` node of the XML, but this does not throw any error.

Here is the XML output of my Page Template:

> AddIndexData: Found Search Index Data in package:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<indexdata> 
    <url>/en/support/product-support/software/Zetasizer-family-software-update-v7-10.html</url> 
    <title>Zetasizer family software update v7.10</title> 
    <publicationid>22</publicationid> 
    <schemaid>102</schemaid> 
    <itemtype>64</itemtype> 
    <parentsgid>1242</parentsgid> 
    <sgid>1242</sgid> 
    <sgid>159</sgid> 
    <sgid>158</sgid> 
    <sgid>8</sgid> 
    <type>0</type> 
    <body>Zetasizer family s .......... feature key.</body> 
    <custom> 
        <date>2014-04-16T15:21:46.0000000Z</date> 
        <product>8023</product> 
        <product>8016</product> 
        <product>8017</product> 
        <language>3006</language> 
        <language>3011</language> 
        <extendeddocumentType>9758</extendeddocumentType> 
    </custom> 
</indexdata>
```

In above XML:

```
<custom> 
    <date>2014-04-16T15:21:46.0000000Z</date> 
    <product>8023</product> 
    <product>8016</product> 
    <product>8017</product> 
    <language>3006</language> 
    <language>3011</language> 
    <extendeddocumentType>9758</extendeddocumentType> 
</custom>
```

The value for `<extendeddocumentType>9758</extendeddocumentType>` definitetly matches the `regex [a-z0-9][a-z0-9_]{0,63}$` so the error in description does not make any sense.

This might be that the value `9758` is not the expected value of this field, I am not sure as `9758` is not the actual value I have in metadata, my default Radio Button is set to `Software Products` radio.

Can anyone help me here?

**For now I have a work around in place:** >> Sorry below did not work actually.

1. Copy the Page that is currently failing
2. Publish that copy

This worked with no errors. This part is still unclear to me, why it behaves this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're saying:

> The value for <extendeddocumentType>9758</extendeddocumentType> definitetly matches the regex [a-z0-9][a-z0-9_]{0,63}$ so the error in description does not make any sense.

But that's not true, this regex only allows lowercased strings for field names. So, if you lowercase your field name (extendeddocumentType) in the custom TBB Parameter Schema or Component Template Metadata Schema, it should work.

Comment: My bad, yes.. that's not matching... I am checking this with lowercase value and Mark this as an answer in a bit. Thanks Rai !